# Efficiently find top-N values from multiple columns independently in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to get the top n frequency count for all the columns in a dataframe

```
counts = (df.rdd
    .flatMap(lambda x: x.asDict().items())
    .map(lambda x: (x, 1))
    .reduceByKey(add))
```

and I get this:
((Column Name/Value), count)

```
(('name', 'Dominion Range 08357'), 1)
(('id', 52132), 1)
(('nametype', 'Valid'), 10)
(('recclass', 'L6'), 2)
(('mass (g)', 8.9), 1)
(('fall', 'Found'), 10)
(('year', '01/01/2008 12:00:00 AM'), 2)
(('reclat', 0.0), 1)
(('reclong', 0.0), 1)
(('GeoLocation', '(0.000000, 0.000000)'), 1)
(('name', 'Yamato 792863'), 1)
(('id', 28212), 1)
(('recclass', 'H5'), 3)
(('mass (g)', 132.25), 1)
(('year', '01/01/1979 12:00:00 AM'), 1)
(('reclat', -71.5), 1)
(('reclong', 35.66667), 1)
(('GeoLocation', '(-71.500000, 35.666670)'), 1)
```

After that I am trying to get the top 10 values:

```
(counts
    .groupBy(lambda x: x[0])
    .flatMap(lambda g: nlargest(10, g[1], key=lambda x: x[1])))
```

But I am getting the same results.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out. I was missing and extra index in `groupBy`

```
counts = (df.rdd
    .flatMap(lambda x: x.asDict().items())
    .map(lambda x: (x, 1))
    .reduceByKey(add)
    .groupBy(lambda x: x[0][0])
    .flatMap(lambda g: nlargest(3, g[1], key=lambda x: x[1])))
```